# Predictably transform complex, nested json object arrays

Tags: json

Given a highly nested, complex (yet predictable) array of javacript objects how can I transform them into other custom objects?
An API returns to me these arrays and I want to change them for my use. Rename a few fields, move nested objects "up" a level, compute a few values. 
I don't want to write a ton of code to loop over each one that I need to maintain.
I guess I'm looking for something like xslt does for xml.
Is there a library out there for me?

Comment: the best way is to convert them into array and flatten them

Answer (score 0):

ES6 js Destructuring seems to be the way to go